# Is there a word for not having your/ or a race's opinion being taken into account? More of a discrimination/racism type of word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for not having your/ or a race's opinion being taken into account? More of a discrimination/racism type of word.

For example.

"Discrimination can be demonstrated through insulting, marginalizing, or [word] a race."

Help is greatly appreciated, even the closest word related to this is fine.

Comment: Except that's not what the definition of *discrimination* is. It's forming an unwarranted bias against (or for) someone or something, or having a preconceived notion. Discrimination can *result* in insults or marginalization, but neither of those things are actually discrimination *themselves*. (It's similarly inaccurate to say that discrimination can be demonstrated through murder—or nepotism, in the case of favourable discrimination.)

Comment: According to NOAD discrimination is any unjust or prejudicial treatment of different categories of people or things. I'd say that this both means and can be demonstrated by insults and marginalization―and much else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use ***exclude*** in this context (though perhaps its noun form ***exclusion*** conveys this meaning better).

> "Discrimination can be demonstrated through insulting, marginalizing,
>   or [***excluding***]/[***exclusion*** of] a race (from something like decision
>   making)."

ODO:

> **[exclude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exclude)**
>   *VERB* [WITH OBJECT]
>   **1** Deny (someone) access to a place, group, or privilege.
>
> ‘As we saw above, early migrants were largely excluded from access to public housing by complex residence and qualification rules.’
>
> **[exclusion](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exclusion)**
>   *NOUN* [mass noun]
>   **1** The process of excluding or the state of being excluded.
>
> ‘I wasn't sure whether the issue was one of social privilege or gender
>   exclusion, or both.’
>
> ‘Both sides of this issue reflect the social and geographical
>   exclusion of black people in a discriminatory society.’